# Angular2+ style parent that outside component scope

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to do the following....

**app.component.html**

```
   <app-nav></app-nav>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="page-content clearfix">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Can I apply following CSS to `page-wrapper` and `page-content` class when router to particular `Component` and after going to other `Component` remove as it is... ?

**CSS**

```
.page-content {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1367px) {
  .page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I also try `View Encapsulation` option (None) but this apply style to header which is always their... even I route to other `Component`.

```
@Component({
// ...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [
  // ...
]
})
```

Comment: You mean, when you are in `componentX` you want to apply some styles to `page-wrapper` and when you are in `componentY` you want to change the styles of `page-wrapper` and so on... ?

Comment: you can check this link  @  https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation  i hope this helps .

Comment: @Mr_Perfect yes only style untill componentX still present

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track and need to style the `page-wrapper` and `page-content` from each component that displayed in the `<router-outlet>` by using `ViewEncapsulation.None`. So, by writing styles like this, every time the parent elements's(`page-wrapper` and `page-content`) styles will be override based on component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-x',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [`
      .page-wrapper, .page-content{
          background-color: red;
      }
    `]
});


@Component({
    selector: 'component-y',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [`
      .page-wrapper, .page-content{
          background-color: green;
      }
    `]
});
```